# Is there any way to link to VSTS 2010 from Delphi XE2?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, team-explorer

I am working on Delphi XE2 version. We are planning to move our code base from JEDI to VSTS 2010. Is there any way to add plugin (like JEDI) or link VSTS 2010 to Delphi XE2?

Does Delphi XE2 support such kind of functionality or any plug-in?

**Update :** As per my knowledge, Currently there is no integration of JEDI with Delphi XE2 that's the reason we are looking for some other version control utility which integrates with Delphi XE2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [SourceConneXion for RAD Studio\Delphi XE2](http://www.epocalipse.com/downloads.htm) which got released this month. It is a good product for linking your Delphi IDE to a Team Foundation Server.

A warning is in place: [Epocalipse has been very slow at adopting new Delphi versions](http://www.epocalipse.com/index.htm).

Two other paths are also possible:

- use [SvnBridge](http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/) (either on your workstation or on the TFS server) to access TFS through the protocol that SVN ([Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/)) uses. You loose a bit of the integration (SVN exposes less than what TFS can do) but works very well and you can use the Delphi XE2 SVN integration. [CodePlex uses this approach](http://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20TortoiseSVN%20with%20CodePlex).
- use Visual Studio Team Explorer ([2010 version](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=329)) which means doing your version control stuff outside of your Delphi IDE. I've done this in the past, and it actually is pretty OK.

Comment: What are the best and recommended options for this?

Comment: Just try and decide what works best for you. It all depends on how you work, and how much Delphi integration you want/need.

Comment: I am planning to go for SVN integration. But where can I get pros and cons for the same?

Comment: Tell us more in the question on how you use the JEDI integration, then people might be able to help you out better.

Comment: As per my knowledge, Currently there is no integration of JEDI with Delphi XE2 that's the reason we are looking for some other version control utility which integrates with Delphi XE2.

Comment: Ah, OK. It has been a while since I used the JEDI VCS. Can you describe which JEDI VCS integration features you use on your previous Delphi version?

Comment: I have used Delphi 4 with JEDI inbuilt in IDE. Now that is not provided by Delphi XE2.

Comment: Which JEDI VCL features did you use in Delphi 4?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to use the MSSCCI provider, which would allow you to use the old SourceSafe integration built into older IDE's